# How to identify the specific entity while scrapping wikipedia page by python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, wikipedia

My question is about how to scrape specific entity from wikipedia page.

I am using wikipedia api and got an array of all links from the page
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_painters_by_name_beginning_with_%22A%22

```
import re
paintersListArray = []
check = re.compile("List of painters by name*")
for link in dt.links:
    if check.match(link):
        paintersListArray.append(wikipedia.page(link, auto_suggest=False))
paintersListArray[0]
```

The resulting list is

> 'Abram Arkhipov',  'Abstract expressionist',  'Ai Xuan',  'Aimitsu',
> 'Albert Anker',...

Question 1. How do I remove all non-names of the painters?
Question 2. If I want to find all mentioned on the wikipedia page paintings of specific painter, is there is any general way to do this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

What we do is we get the HTML of the webpage and then we use BeautifulSoup to get all the 'li'(The webpage is formatted where all the information we want is in this part). After we do that we make sure all the text in the `printers` list is only printers and not other information.

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_painters_by_name_beginning_with_%22A%22"

response = requests.get(url)
text = response.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(text, 'html.parser')
printers = soup.find_all('li')
printers = [printer.text for printer in printers if printer.text.count("(") == 1 and printer.text.count("),") == 1]
print(printers)
```

Comment: why "li"? not sure, I understood.

Comment: https://i.gyazo.com/22a3459bd205d6c306b0085761b4f5e4.png look at this image You see how all the information is in 'li'???

Comment: what do you mean by "all the text in the printers"? what are the printers?
Also, what tool did you use to look the structure of web page like this?

Comment: @mary press f12 and go to the elements tab to see HTML of a window when I refer to printers I am talking about the list in this line `printers = soup.find_all('li')
`